# Git rebase interactive/ -i: what happens if I abort/or dont save the rebase

Tags: git

This is the scenario:

- made several commits
- wanted to edit a certain commit
- git rebase -i 'commit-hash'
- choose wrong commit hash so I closed the editor window(sublime)
- terminal(iterm) git message: `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/*`

my question is:

1. what exactly just happened?
2. did it actually rebase onto (x)-amount of commits onto eachother?
3. if so, how can I undo this?

Comment: Git ran the interactive rebase with your (unchanged) rebase plan but since no modifications were necessary, none of the original commits are affected. So you will end up in the same situation you started from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not actually change anything in the editor, nothing will change.  In general `git rebase` allows you to move a branch to a new base commit.  However, Git actually accomplishes this by creating new commits.  So, one way to tell if a rebase occurred is to look at the commit hashes.  If there are no new ones, then a rebase did not occur.  The `-i` option simply allows you to rebase with more flexibility.  Such as squashing or splitting commits.